# return a string from a function in a class in python

Tags: python, string, class, return

Cannot return a string from a python class to another python class.

Created two classes and need to get a string from one to the other. I keep getting the message -
`'app.classes.xxx' has no attribute 'returnDBString'`

**Class1.py**

```py
from app.classes import DBManager

 def CustomerSetup(self, user_id):
        db = DBManager.returnDBString()
        cnxn = pdc.connect(db)
```

**DBManager.py**

```py
class DBManager():

    def returnDBString():
        return 'Database string and connection info'

    def returnConnection():
        return pdc.connect(returnDBString())
```

I was expecting to get back the actual string in the class, but I keep getting the error

`app.classes.DBManager' has no attribute 'returnDBString`

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with returning strings.

For some reason you have put your function inside a class, which just happens to have the same name as the module it is in. But Python is not Java; functions don't need to be in classes, and if you do define a class then you need to import it specifically, not just the module (or, at least, refer to it via the module).

In any case, you should remove the class declaration and just put your two functions directly at module level.

Comment: this sounds more confusing..I have a class that is filled with different db functions I need to execute.  If I remove Class DBManager(), how do you call the returnDBString() from class1.py?

Comment: I  don't understand your comment. If you import class1, then you can call `class1.returnDBString()`. Or in your case, you already do `from app.classes import DBManager` so you can still do `DBManager.returnDBString()`. The point is that there is no need for a class in there at all.

Answer (score 0):

Decorate the method with @classmethod if it makes sense to have this method under DBManager

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the class in `Class1.py`, and make `pdc` available to it:

```
db = DBManager.DBManager(pdc).returnDBString()
```

Note the parens, `DBManager()`.

You'll also need to write your `DBManager` class like so:

```py
class DBManager():

    def __init__(self, pdx):
        self.pdx = pdx

    def returnDBString(self):
        return 'Database string and connection info'

    def returnConnection(self):
        return self.pdc.connect(self.returnDBString())
```

Comment: this sounds like what I am after, but I get a 'module' object is not callable' error when I call db = DBManager(pdc).returnConnection() from the first class

Comment: Ah, right, the module and the class have the same name. This is unusual - in Python, module names are usually all_lowercase, and classes CamelCase. I'll update.

Comment: Of course, this assumes that you want a class. It's also possible to define functions outside of classes, and call them directly. Python is not Java!

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of usability of module with classes.
There are 2 solution to your problem:

1) If you create class with member function in **DBManager.py** and want to use it some different file.Then, first thing which should come into you mind that a class is nothing without an class object. You need to create an object of your class and call into returnDBString() with that object. keep in mind you need to create constructor **init**() as well of you class, its incomplete in your code.

`def CustomerSetup(self, user_id):
     DBObject = DBManager()
     db = DBObject.returnDBString()`

2) Don't have class in **DBManager.py**, delete class and have same function without class. In this case your current code Class1.py would work.